# Javascript replace: don't split word on hyphen (regular expressions)

Tags: javascript, regex

I use a `replace` to wrap all the words in a string with `<a/>` tags, but if a word contains a dash or hyphen it splits the word, e.g: `hello-there` becomes `hello - <a>there</a>`.

This is what I use now:

```
string.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, '<a href="javascript:void(0)">$1</a>');
```

Also, how can I remove periods or commas from the words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="hello-there";

document.write(str.replace(/\b([\w+-]+)\b/g,'<a href="javascript:void(0)">$1</a>')
);

</script>
```

Comment: Note: The `+` inside the character class will match a literal `+` character - it's not acting as a quantifier.

Answer (score 3):

`\w` in regexes doesn't include dashes (`-`), so your match will explicitly exclude those from your word wrapping. In other words, given

```
hello-there
```

your regex will see:

```
word(hello) non-word(-)  word(there)
```

Try this:

```
replace(/\b([\w-])+\b/, ...)
```

to explicitly include dashes in the "this is part of a word" class.

Comment: Note

      "words-letters".replace(/\b([\w-]+)\b/g, '') //returns ""
             "words-".replace(/\b([\w-]+)\b/g, '') //returns "-" because the char before the dash is a letter.